# Laravel Eloquent populates collection with id 1 always

Tags: sql, laravel-5

I have a project on laravel 5.
I wrote an SQL to select games from database, and after executing it, I got models collection, where every model has id = 1.

This is my query:

```
select * from `games` left join `game_vendors` on `games`.`vendor_id` = 
`game_vendors`.`id` where `game_vendors`.`name` != 'some_vendor' and 
`games`.`id` not in (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12);
```

checked this query in mysql terminal - all is fine, id's are correct, but on postman or in the browser, I got this

```
array(2021) {
  [0]=>
  array(32) {
    ["id"] => int(1)
  [1]=>
  array(32) {
    ["id"] => int(1)
  ...
  ...
  ...
  [24]=>
   array(32) {
    ["id"] => int(1)
```

Model class contains this:

```
class Game extends Model {
protected $table = 'games';

public function vendor()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\GameVendor', 'vendor_id', 'id');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Laravel Eloquent Relationship and "WHERE NOT IN"

Update Model as

```
class Game extends Model {
protected $table = 'games';

public function vendor()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\GameVendor', 'vendor_id', 'id')->where('name', '!=' ,'some_vendor');
}
```

And use Eloquent as

```
$games = Game::whereNotIn('id',[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12])->get();
foreach($games as $game){
    $game->vendor->name
}
```

Comment: name != 'some_vendor' - it's dynamically created condition, I can't write it inside the model

Comment: for dynamic conditions

    foreach($games as $game){
        if($game->vendor->name != $someDynamicVal){
            //code
        }
    }

Comment: or use grouping in raw db query